# Setting the fortran compiler in f2py

Tags: python, c, compilation, fortran, f2py

I am trying to run the f2py [example](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~pbechler/numpy_doc/user/c-info.python-as-glue.html) to create the compiled extension module¶:

```
# import os
# os.environ["CC"] = "gcc" 
# os.environ["CXX"] = "g++"

# Using post-0.2.2 scipy_distutils to display fortran compilers
from scipy_distutils.fcompiler import new_fcompiler
compiler = new_fcompiler() # or new_fcompiler(compiler='intel')
compiler.dump_properties()

#Generate add.f wrapper
from numpy import f2py
with open("add.f") as sourcefile:
    sourcecode = sourcefile.read()
    print 'Fortran code'
    print sourcecode

# f2py.compile(sourcecode, modulename='add', extra_args = '--compiler=gnu --fcompiler=gnu')
f2py.compile(sourcecode, modulename='add', extra_args = '--fcompiler=gfortran')
# f2py.compile(sourcecode, modulename='add')

import add
```

However, the code does not work. I believe it is because it is not using the compiler installed (Operative system is ubuntu 12.04). However, despite using the "--fcompile" argument or changing the "CC" and "CXX" entries it is still not working....

This is the complete error log. Please any advice would be most welcome:

```
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifc
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
Could not locate executable ifort
customize IntelFCompiler
customize LaheyFCompiler
customize PGroupFCompiler
customize AbsoftFCompiler
customize NAGFCompiler
customize VastFCompiler
customize GnuFCompiler
customize CompaqFCompiler
customize IntelItaniumFCompiler
customize G95FCompiler
customize GnuFCompiler
GnuFCompiler instance properties:
  archiver        = ['ar', '-cr']
  compile_switch  = '-c'
  compiler_f77    = ['f77', '-Wall', '-fno-second-underscore']
  compiler_f90    = None
  compiler_fix    = None
  libraries       = []
  library_dirs    = []
  linker_so       = ['f77', '-Wall']
  object_switch   = '-o '
  ranlib          = ['ranlib']
  version_cmd     = ['f77', '--version']
Fortran code
C
      SUBROUTINE ZADD(A,B,C,N)
C
      DOUBLE COMPLEX A(*)
      DOUBLE COMPLEX B(*)
      DOUBLE COMPLEX C(*)
      INTEGER N
      DO 20 J = 1, N
         C(J) = A(J)+B(J)
 20   CONTINUE
      END

Unknown vendor: "gfortran"
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "add" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> /tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/addmodule.c
creating /tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7
Reading fortran codes...
    Reading file '/tmp/tmpi2WwBV.f' (format:fix,strict)
Post-processing...
    Block: add
            Block: zadd
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
    Building module "add"...
        Constructing wrapper function "zadd"...
getarrdims:warning: assumed shape array, using 0 instead of '*'
getarrdims:warning: assumed shape array, using 0 instead of '*'
getarrdims:warning: assumed shape array, using 0 instead of '*'
          zadd(a,b,c,n)
    Wrote C/API module "add" to file "/tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/addmodule.c"
  adding '/tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding '/tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
copying /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c -> /tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7
copying /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.h -> /tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran
Found executable /home/vital/Iraf/unix/hlib/f77.sh
Found executable /usr/bin/ranlib
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'add' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: gfortran -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC

creating /tmp/tmpNKECn3/tmp
creating /tmp/tmpNKECn3/tmp/tmpNKECn3
creating /tmp/tmpNKECn3/tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7
compile options: '-I/tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
gfortran: /tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/addmodule.c
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1781:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from /tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.h:13,
                 from /tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/addmodule.c:19:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
/tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/addmodule.c:105:12: warning: ‘f2py_size’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int f2py_size(PyArrayObject* var, ...)
            ^
gfortran: /tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1781:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from /tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.h:13,
                 from /tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c:2:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
compiling Fortran sources
Fortran f77 compiler: /home/vital/Iraf/unix/hlib//f77.sh -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran f90 compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran fix compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops
compile options: '-I/tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
f77.sh:f77: /tmp/tmpi2WwBV.f
Cannot open file tmpi2WwBV.f
gcc: error: tmpi2WwBV.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Cannot open file tmpi2WwBV.f
gcc: error: tmpi2WwBV.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
error: Command "/home/vital/Iraf/unix/hlib//f77.sh -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops -I/tmp/tmpNKECn3/src.linux-x86_64-2.7 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c -c /tmp/tmpi2WwBV.f -o /tmp/tmpNKECn3/tmp/tmpi2WwBV.o" failed with exit status 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vital/git/pyResources/pyResources/Tutorials/test_f2py.py", line 21, in <module>
    import add
ImportError: No module named add
```

P.S. Iraf is an astronomical software not a compiler.

Edit 1:

Using the correct import as suggested by jthomas I get a shorter error but still it is trying to use the script in the IRAF folder. This is the complete error message using that code:

```
Gnu95FCompiler instance properties:
  compile_switch  = '-c'
  libraries       = []
  library_dirs    = []
  object_switch   = '-o '
Fortran code
C
      SUBROUTINE ZADD(A,B,C,N)
C
      DOUBLE COMPLEX A(*)
      DOUBLE COMPLEX B(*)
      DOUBLE COMPLEX C(*)
      INTEGER N
      DO 20 J = 1, N
         C(J) = A(J)+B(J)
 20   CONTINUE
      END

Unknown vendor: "gfortran"
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "add" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> /tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/addmodule.c
creating /tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7
Reading fortran codes...
    Reading file '/tmp/tmph5mvme.f' (format:fix,strict)
Post-processing...
    Block: add
            Block: zadd
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
    Building module "add"...
        Constructing wrapper function "zadd"...
getarrdims:warning: assumed shape array, using 0 instead of '*'
getarrdims:warning: assumed shape array, using 0 instead of '*'
getarrdims:warning: assumed shape array, using 0 instead of '*'
          zadd(a,b,c,n)
    Wrote C/API module "add" to file "/tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/addmodule.c"
  adding '/tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding '/tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
copying /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c -> /tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7
copying /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.h -> /tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran
Found executable /home/vital/Iraf/unix/hlib/f77.sh
Found executable /usr/bin/ranlib
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'add' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC

creating /tmp/tmp_KRxI5/tmp
creating /tmp/tmp_KRxI5/tmp/tmp_KRxI5
creating /tmp/tmp_KRxI5/tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7
compile options: '-I/tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
gcc: /tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/addmodule.c
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1781:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from /tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.h:13,
                 from /tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/addmodule.c:19:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
/tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/addmodule.c:105:12: warning: ‘f2py_size’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int f2py_size(PyArrayObject* var, ...)
            ^
gcc: /tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1781:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from /tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.h:13,
                 from /tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c:2:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
compiling Fortran sources
Fortran f77 compiler: /home/vital/Iraf/unix/hlib//f77.sh -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran f90 compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran fix compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops
compile options: '-I/tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
f77.sh:f77: /tmp/tmph5mvme.f
Cannot open file tmph5mvme.f
gcc: error: tmph5mvme.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Cannot open file tmph5mvme.f
gcc: error: tmph5mvme.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
error: Command "/home/vital/Iraf/unix/hlib//f77.sh -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops -I/tmp/tmp_KRxI5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c -c /tmp/tmph5mvme.f -o /tmp/tmp_KRxI5/tmp/tmph5mvme.o" failed with exit status 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vital/git/pyResources/pyResources/Tutorials/test_f2py.py", line 42, in <module>
    import add
ImportError: No module named add
```

EDIT 2: When changing the extension to .f90 and defining the fortran compiler location (using whereis) I get the following error:

```
Gnu95FCompiler instance properties:
  compile_switch  = '-c'
  libraries       = []
  library_dirs    = []
  object_switch   = '-o '
Fortran code
C
      SUBROUTINE ZADD(A,B,C,N)
C
      DOUBLE COMPLEX A(*)
      DOUBLE COMPLEX B(*)
      DOUBLE COMPLEX C(*)
      INTEGER N
      DO 20 J = 1, N
         C(J) = A(J)+B(J)
 20   CONTINUE
      END

Unknown vendor: "/usr/bin/gfortran"
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "add" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> /tmp/tmpHgqM4n/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/addmodule.c
creating /tmp/tmpHgqM4n/src.linux-x86_64-2.7
Reading fortran codes...
    Reading file '/tmp/tmpiLO46g.f' (format:fix,strict)
Post-processing...
    Block: add
            Block: zadd
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
    Building module "add"...
        Constructing wrapper function "zadd"...
getarrdims:warning: assumed shape array, using 0 instead of '*'
getarrdims:warning: assumed shape array, using 0 instead of '*'
getarrdims:warning: assumed shape array, using 0 instead of '*'
          zadd(a,b,c,n)
    Wrote C/API module "add" to file "/tmp/tmpHgqM4n/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/addmodule.c"
  adding '/tmp/tmpHgqM4n/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding '/tmp/tmpHgqM4n/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
copying /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c -> /tmp/tmpHgqM4n/src.linux-x86_64-2.7
copying /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.h -> /tmp/tmpHgqM4n/src.linux-x86_64-2.7
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix' with '/usr/bin/gfortran' compiler. Supported compilers are: g95,compaq,none,intele,ibm,gnu,mips,lahey,nag,pathf95,intelem,gnu95,intelv,intelvem,absoft,intelev,pg,sun,hpux,vast,intel)
warning: build_ext: f77_compiler=/usr/bin/gfortran is not available.

building 'add' extension
error: extension 'add' has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
```

EDIT 3:

Using the arguments:

```
f2py.compile(sourcecode, modulename='add', extra_args = '-c --help-fcompiler')
```

I get the following output:

```
Gnu95FCompiler instance properties:
  archiver        = ['/usr/bin/gfortran', '-cr']
  compile_switch  = '-c'
  compiler_f77    = ['/home/vital/Iraf/unix/hlib//f77.sh', '-Wall', '-g', '-
                    ffixed-form', '-fno-second-underscore', '-fPIC', '-O3', '-
                    funroll-loops']
  compiler_f90    = ['/usr/bin/gfortran', '-Wall', '-g', '-fno-second-
                    underscore', '-fPIC', '-O3', '-funroll-loops']
  compiler_fix    = ['/usr/bin/gfortran', '-Wall', '-g', '-ffixed-form', '-
                    fno-second-underscore', '-Wall', '-g', '-fno-second-
                    underscore', '-fPIC', '-O3', '-funroll-loops']
  libraries       = ['gfortran']
  library_dirs    = []
  linker_exe      = ['/usr/bin/gfortran', '-Wall', '-Wall']
  linker_so       = ['/usr/bin/gfortran', '-Wall', '-g', '-Wall', '-g', '-
                    shared']
  object_switch   = '-o '
  ranlib          = ['/usr/bin/ranlib']
  version         = LooseVersion ('4.8')
  version_cmd     = ['/usr/bin/gfortran', '-dumpversion']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/f2py/f2py2e.py", line 648, in main
    run_compile()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/f2py/f2py2e.py", line 633, in run_compile
    setup(ext_modules=[ext])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 137, in setup
    ok = dist.parse_command_line()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 467, in parse_command_line
    args = self._parse_command_opts(parser, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 576, in _parse_command_opts
    func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/command/config_compiler.py", line 15, in show_fortran_compilers
    show_fcompilers(dist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/__init__.py", line 889, in show_fcompilers
    c.customize(dist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/__init__.py", line 502, in customize
    get_flags('opt', oflags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/__init__.py", line 493, in get_flags
    flags.extend(getattr(self.flag_vars, tag))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/environment.py", line 39, in __getattr__
    return self._get_var(name, conf_desc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/environment.py", line 53, in _get_var
    var = self._hook_handler(name, hook)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/__init__.py", line 700, in _environment_hook
    return hook()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/gnu.py", line 206, in get_flags_opt
    v = self.get_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/__init__.py", line 432, in get_version
    version = CCompiler.get_version(self, force=force, ok_status=ok_status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 491, in CCompiler_get_version
    version = matcher(output)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/gnu.py", line 79, in version_match
    v = self.gnu_version_match(version_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/gnu.py", line 76, in gnu_version_match
    raise ValueError(err + version_string)
ValueError: A valid Fortran version was not found in this string:
invalid parameter -dumpversion
```

Comment: What does `f2py -c --help-fcompiler` return? Look for "Fortran compilers found".

Comment: @unutbu thank you for your interest I added the result in Edit 3

Comment: What do you get when you run `f2py -c --help-fcompiler` from the command line? And is it necessary to run `f2py` from inside a Python script? Or do you just want to compile the `add` module any way you can?

Comment: @unutbu thanks again: I can run f2py as  /usr/bin/f2py -c -m add add.f90. This generates the add.so which python at least can "import add". I can run this command using popen if needed. If you add a reply I can set it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [tutorial docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/c-info.python-as-glue.html#creating-a-compiled-extension-module), an easy way to use f2py is to run from the command line

```
f2py -c -m add add.f
```

This creates the module file `add.so` (or `add.pyd`, depending on your OS), which can be imported into Python scripts with

```
import add
```

provided `add.so` is in a directory listed in `sys.path`.

Answer (score 2):

f2py is now maintained as part of numpy. Altering your example as follows compiles just fine.

```
# import os
# os.environ["CC"] = "gcc"
# os.environ["CXX"] = "g++"

# Using post-0.2.2 scipy_distutils to display fortran compilers
from numpy.distutils.fcompiler import new_fcompiler
compiler = new_fcompiler() # or new_fcompiler(compiler='intel')
compiler.dump_properties()

#Generate add.f wrapper
from numpy import f2py
with open("add.f") as sourcefile:
    sourcecode = sourcefile.read()
    print 'Fortran code'
    print sourcecode

# f2py.compile(sourcecode, modulename='add', extra_args = '--compiler=gnu --fcompiler=g$
f2py.compile(sourcecode, modulename='add', extra_args = '--fcompiler=gfortran')
# f2py.compile(sourcecode, modulename='add')

import add
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply: I used your import but I still get a very similar error... It is trying to use the IRAF script as compiler. Do you have please any suggestion?. I included the new error message in the question

Comment: I have never used IRAF, but from your error message, and looking around online, it appears to include a Fortran 77 compiler and your path points to that compiler for compiling Fortran 77. Since your program can be compiled using later Fortran editions, try changing the extension of add.f from .f to .f90. You will need to alter the extension of the file itself as well as its reference in your .py file. Also, for your compiled program to be usable I think you will need to make a few changes to it, but perhaps that would be better address in another question after it will at least compile.

Comment: Thanks again for your time... I have tried your code but with the f90 extension and I still get the same error... Funny thing when I try to give the full address for the compiler : --fcompiler =  /usr/bin/gfortran I get the error: " don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix' with '/usr/bin/gfortran' compiler." "warning: build_ext: f77_compiler=/usr/bin/gfortran is not available."

Comment: As posted by @unutbu, you could try alternative (simpler) methods for compiling. His answer is the method I typically use. I should have pointed that out sooner.

Comment: This is an indirect solution to the problem but it is thanks to you and @unutbu I can run the f2py at least. Thanks again jthomas