# Installing f2py in ubuntu

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I wonder if anyone could help me with one issue: I am using ubuntu 12.04 and I wanted to install f2py. However the version found here:

https://sysbio.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/index.html#installation

Gives me an error with python 2.7.6. This issue arises to many users due to word "as" becoming a keyword since python 2.6 (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.f2py.user/1802)

Hence which is the updated way to install f2py? Or using the one from numpy?

Thanks

Vital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version you link to is very very old. The [installation instructions](https://sysbio.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/FAQ.html#installation) refer to Python2.1!

You'll find [a newer version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/F2PY/2.45.241_1926) by [searching PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=f2py&submit=search). But [the homepage](https://sysbio.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/) for that package states that, as of 2007-07-19,

> F2PY is now part of NumPy. All the development and maintenance of F2PY is carried out under NumPy SVN tree.

So the easiest way to install f2py on ubuntu is
to install numpy:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply: I am trying to use f2py from the terminal (as in the many examples online) but I am having issues running the command within python (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952163/setting-the-fortran-compiler-in-f2py). Do you know how to use it to generate the compiled extension module outside python?. (The links in the website are outdated)